# can you open a excel file directly with google sheets api

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

how can I open a excel file directly with google sheets api

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge, however, using the Drive API you can [upload and convert an Excel file to Sheets format](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) automatically. This could then be used by the Sheets API. This may or may not work as a substitute in your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can read a .xlsx file as a binary blob from Google Apps Script API. So if you want to read the xlsx formatted file and do all the work of interpreting it yourself, then sure you can. But that's essentially writing the entire MS Excel interpreter in Google Script.